# C++ const data initialization

Tags: c++, constants

In C++ 'const' is compute during compile-time or run-time?
Why I can assign value at run-time?

```
class A{
   public:
       const int a;
   A():a{100}{    // if const's need compile-time evaluate why we can do this
    }
};
```

main:

```
A* a = new A(); // const do no assign(or initialization?) until run-time...
```

Comment: Who told you const can only be set at compile time?

Comment: @Galik C#'s 'const' :)) but its very different ))

Comment: @Zed123456: Indeed, different languages are different. Don't try to guess how one language works based on your understanding of a different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++ `const` is compute during compile-time or run-time?

It depends. If it's a non-member variable, initialised by a constant expression, then the value can be assigned by the compiler. If it's a non-static class member, or initialised with a value not known at compile time, then it will have to be initialised at run-time.

> Why I can assign value at run-time?

You can't. You can initialise it with a run-time value, but you can't assign a new value after initialisation. That's what `const` means.

Comment: If it's a local variable initialised with a constant expression, it's also a compile-time constant, which is why `template <int N> void f() { } int main() { const int i = 0; f<i>(); }` is a valid program (that does nothing).

Comment: @hvd: Yes, you're right. I think my update is more or less accurate, trying not to complicate the answer by covering all the nuances of these rules.

Comment: @Zed123456: `readonly` only tells compiler that the field can only be modified (i.e. set) inside the constructor (or during class initialization).

Comment: @MikeSeymour It does look mostly correct now, and I think you're probably right that more details would make your answer harder to follow, so fair enough. :)